# Why are there two '.' before sp_executesql

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
set @sql = 'exec '+ QUOTENAME(@dbname) + '..sp_executesql N''create schema MyNewSchema'''
exec (@sql)
```

Why are there  two '.' before sp_executesql? I think that should be one, shouldn't?

Comment: It means that the schema is omitted and will be used the default schema of your current login session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general form of the 4 part dotted notation is:

```
servername.database.schema.object
```

[From MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx), the general form can be:

```
server_name .[database_name].[schema_name].object_name
| database_name.[schema_name].object_name
| schema_name.object_name
| object_name
```

In your case, the schema has been omitted (the second line). Although the coder here as assumed that `dbo.sp_executesql` is the only object with this name, it is dangerous practice - it would be safer to use `dbName.dbo.sp_executesql` (Rationale as per @Hamlet's comment, viz that without an explicit schema, sql will first look for an object with this name in the current login's default schema, before reverting to the `dbo` schema)

Answer (score 2):

It's a way to use the default schema of the user, you can omit the schema name:

```
databasename..tablename
```

General notation:

> The server, database, and owner names are known as the qualifiers of
>   the object name. When you refer to an object, you do not have to
>   specify the server, database, and owner. The qualifiers can be omitted
>   by marking their positions with a period. The valid forms of object
>   names include the following:
>
> server_name.database_name.schema_name.object_name
>
> server_name.database_name..object_name
>
> server_name..schema_name.object_name
>
> server_name...object_name
>
> database_name.schema_name.object_name
>
> database_name..object_name
>
> schema_name.object_name
>
> object_name
>
> An object name that specifies all four parts is known as a fully
>   qualified name. Each object that is created in Microsoft SQL Server
>   must have a unique, fully qualified name. For example, there can be
>   two tables named xyz in the same database if they have different
>   owners.
>
> Most object references use three-part names. The default server_name
>   is the local server. The default database_name is the current database
>   of the connection. The default schema_name is the default schema of
>   the user submitting the statement. Unless otherwise configured, the
>   default schema of new users is the dbo schema.

Ref: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879%28v=sql.105%29.aspx